# Node.js app not reading .env file/variables inside linux aws ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and I've started and configured an EC2 instance with linux.
I made a service worker to auto start the program and told it where the .env file is.
Below is how I made the service worker file

`sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/NodeServer.service`

I then pasted this inside that newly created file

```
[Unit]
Description=My Node Server
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/ec2-user/earmark-backend/dist/api/server.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=earmark-backend-server
User=ec2-user
EnvironmentFile=/home/ec2-user/earmark-backend/.env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To create the .env file I ran this command
`sudo vim /home/ec2-user/earmark-backend/.env`

inside the .env file I pasted this code

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID=<env_var>

PLAID_SECRET=<env_var>

PLAID_ENV=sandbox

PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions

PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA

PLAID_REDIRECT_URI=<env_var>

PORT=8080

URL=<env_var>
```

Then when I start the service worker via `sudo systemctl start NodeServer.service` and make a request I get the error `"TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value \"undefined\" for header \"PLAID-CLIENT-ID\"\n`

However if I start my server with the command `PLAID_CLIENT_ID=<env_var> PLAID_SECRET=<env_var> PLAID_ENV=sandbox ...(rest of env vars) node ./dist/api/server.js` it works and can read the env variables.

Anyone have any idea why it's not able to read my .env file?

Also, side question: I'd prefer to have my service worker ExecStart command run a bash script, but I'm not exactly sure how I'd setup the script. I have a file `start.sh` and inside I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/ec2-user/earmark-backend
npm i
npm run clean
npm run build
npm run start
```

It's not working though, how would I properly format my .sh file to run those commands on start?

Comment: Looks like you created the .env file as root but are running your Node.js service as ec2-user (who cannot read files owned by root).

Comment: @jarmod Thanks! I deleted the .env file and remade it with the command ```vim /home/ec2-user/earmark-backend/.env``` (removed sudo) and it worked!